# Decompressing single blob in SQLite DB using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, gzip

Inside of my .mbtiles SQLite db, there's a column called `tile_data` holding the information relating to the specific tile that is being queried.

My application is taking a user long/lat as an input and then converting to a `tile_row` and `tile_column` equivalent values, then pulling the single blob with the data inside via the SQL query below.

The query (fully functional, just to show the code) is:

```
string query =
   String.Format("SELECT tile_data from tiles WHERE zoom_level = {0} AND tile_row = {1} AND tile_column = {2}", ZoomLevel, _merc.TileLat, _merc.TileLong);
   SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, DbConn);
   SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

          while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // ...
                }
```

With the result being a **single** blob file, querying `SELECT *` will pull back the single tile with all data.

The blob inside of `tile_data` is a compressed (gzip) vector file that I need to access and work with, but I can't figure out how to decompress it within my application. Most gzip links that I've read through have been regarding file compression and outputting it to a `.txt` (or similar), whereas I'm looking to use this data in memory without needing an external file.

How can I decompress the blob and access he data in memory, rather than an external file?

Comment: You should be able to pass the data to a `MemoryStream`, then pass that to a `GZipStream` with `CompressionMode.Decompress` then pass that to a `StreamReader`.

Comment: You could use `SqlDataReader.GetStream` to allow you to pull in the data in chunks instead of loading the entire file into a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    using(var file = reader.GetStream(0))
    using(var unzip = new GZipStream(file, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using(var fileReader = new StreamReader(unzip))
    {
        while(!fileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on exactly what your file is you might need to substitute a different type of reader.